# Is Rishabha, the founder of Jainism and the avatar of Lord Vishnu, the same characters or two different characters that only share the name?

Tags: jainism

Is Rishabha, the founder of Jainism and the avatar of Lord Vishnu, the same characters or two different characters that only share the name?

I'm Hindu but don't believe that there is a connection between hinduism and jainism, so I believe there are two differents peoples who only share the name